# Deploy multiple office products using startup scripts

Tags: microsoft-office-2010, deployment, startup-scripts

I need to deploy MS Visio 2010 and MS Project 2010 to users that belong to a specific security group. Most of the time users will only need one or the other, but on occasion they will need both. The issue that I'm running into is that multiple instances of the installer cannot be run simultaneously. Has anyone worked out a way to deploy multiple Office products consecutively?

Comment: Write a single script that will deploy both.  Have the script obtain criteria from the AD to decide what steps needs to actually be performed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm making an assumption that you are also using a newer model of Active Directory but you could easily create a GPO to do software deployment and then use item-level targeting on it to ensure the software is only deployed to users of a specific group or however you want to deploy them.

Comment: GPSI is not supported with Office 2010. Microsoft suggests using SCCM or startup scripts to deploy the software. In the meantime I have created a ZAP deployment which seems to be working until I can design a more polished solution.

Comment: Good Point.  One option may be to create a an MSI package that combines both installers.  So for users that need both you would simply provide a combined installer.  You would need to find a tool that can merge multiple EXEs with options into another EXE or MSI package. Not sure if that would work though.

Comment: The OCT allows you to run additional installers after installing but that would mean publishing 'Project', 'Visio', and 'Project & Visio' apps. That could get messy fast and would also mean that I need to have two copies of the installation files. I'm still researching - I'll post an update once I find a final solution.